# Proof of $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+ h)-f(a)}{h}=\ell$ when $\lim_{x\to a}f'(x)=\ell$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ derivable on $\mathbb R$ and that $\lim_{x\to a}f'(x)=\ell$. Show that $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\ell.$$

The proof of my course goes like this:

By mean value theorem, there is $y_h\in ]x,x+h[$ s.t. $$f(x+h)-f(x)=f'(y_h)h$$ and thus $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}f'(y_h)=\ell.$$

QED.

**Question 1: Didn't we only proved that $$\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\ell\ \ ?$$**

**Question 2: May-be by $]x,x+h[$ they mean $\{y\mid x<y<x+h\}$ if $h>0$ and $\{y\mid x+h<y<x\}$ if $h<0$, no ?**

Comment: You've mistakenly switched all your $a$s to $x$s. But yes, the proof for $h\to 0-$ involves finding $z_h\in (x-h,h)$.

Comment: It's a special case of l’Hôpital’s theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Formally, you have to write the "other half" of the proof, the case $h<0$, but the argument is exactly the same.

Comment: Do you think that (even if the mean value theorem doesn't says exactly this, but it could be a corollary). By the mean value theorem (generalized ?), there is $y_h$ s.t. $|y_h|<|h|$ s.t. $$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=f'(y_h)$$ and thus we will have automatically the result. What do you think ?

Comment: If you think about it, usually the MVT is stated as $$f(b)-f(a)=f'(c)\,(b-a),$$ with $a<c<b$. But if $a>b$ the MVT gives you $$f(a)-f(b)=f'(c)\,(a-b),$$ for $b<c<a$. This last expression is also equal to $$f(b)-f(a)=f'(c)\,(b-a).$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You proved right-continuity.  Usually one finishes with "and the case for $(x-h,x)$ is similar."